# Left aligned sidebar with rotated text

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm looking to get a sidebar on every page of an a4 doc with rotated text inside, sort of like below.

I saw this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64887/long-vertical-bar-on-titlepage-with-rotated-text) but I can't quite achieve what I'm after with the solutions there.

It needs to:

- Feature on every page
- Stretch to the top/left edges of the page

I've seen a few ideas using the `tikz` or `background` packages but again, I'm struggling to make it work.

[image: example]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126156/124842

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

This works.  You'll still have to make manual adjustments, like change the color and put in the desired text.  Also, you may want to include an on/off switch in case you want to turn off the box on some pages.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{everypage}


\begin{document}


\AddEverypageHook{  
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page text area.south west)}]
\fill[green,xshift=-7mm,yshift=-0.5ex](0,0) rectangle(5mm,\textheight);
\end{tikzpicture}
}


\lipsum
\end{document}
```